# Changing from Network Service to a Domain Farm Acct

Tags: installation, configuration, service-account

I am attempting to avoid re-installing a farm that was built very quickly using the network service acct for the set up of a single stand alone 2010 environment.

The issue I am running into is the current configuration of the User Profile Synch service amongst other things.

I have just requested an account that I can now use as the Farm Acct.  Is there away I now can use this accrt correctly without reinstallling the farm?

In other words, if I have a domain acct called SPFarm in this case, can I now configure the farm to use this named acct after the fact?

I want to start configuring the Service applications accordingly.  Perhaps the best approach would be a reinstall at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would **definately** start from scratch!

The account used for install has special permissions, and if these have been intertwined with farm account it is a mess. You will spend **far** longer time trying to undo the security related problems in the previous install than starting over.

I usually define a managed account for each service application, one for each application pool that needs a security boundary (eg Intranet, Extranet), one for web service application pool, cache accounts (reader and full control) etc.

I also always create an SPAdmin account that is **not** the same as Install account. This account is farm admin, [Shell Admin](http://sites.wizdim.com/andersrask/sharepoint/how-to-add-a-user-to-the-sharepoint_shell_access-role-on-a-content-database/) and local admin (to be able to add solutions, see services on server and manage security). This is the account you give to your administrator to use for high-permission jobs like adding solutions and managing using Central Administration.

Also remember that farm account is a **service account** and like all service accounts should **never** be used to log in anywhere. Farm account also needs to be local admin *while starting the UPA service instance*. User Profile Synchronization account needs some special ACL permissions on your AD. More info on Spence Harbars guide [here](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

the UPS (User Profile Synch) is a tricky one. You may be able to change the service account but run into problems since the FIM service has already been started (propably with wrong permissions).

Technet has a good resouce in case you are going to reinstall the farm: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx